# $http not returning values from Spring MVC REST controller

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

**How can I change the simple code below so that the simple AngularJS code below can successfully retrieve values from the simple Spring MVC REST Controller below?**  At the moment, nothing happens when I click on the button in the html form.

Here is `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Find Book By ISBN</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="bookApp">
    <div ng-controller="bookController">  
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width=200>
                ISBN:<input type="text" ng-model="book.isbn" />
                <br>
                <button ng-click="findBook()">Find Book</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                ISBN: <span ng-bind="book.isbn"></span>
                <br/>
                Title: <span ng-bind="book.title"></span>
                <br/>
                Author: <span ng-bind="book.author"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is `bookController.js`, which is located in the same directory as `index.html` for testing:

```
// create angular app
var bookApp = angular.module('bookApp', []);

// create angular controller
bookApp.controller('bookController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {  
    var bookId = 1;

    $scope.findBook = function() {
        $http.post('/findbook/' + bookId, $scope.book);
    };

}]);
```

Here is the `Book.java` model class:

```
public class Book {

    private String isbn;
    private String title;
    private String author;

    public void setIsbn(String id){isbn=id;}
    public String getIsbn(){return isbn;}

    public void setTitle(String t){title=t;}
    public String getTitle(){return title;}

    public void setAuthor(String a){author=a;}
    public String getAuthor(){return author;}

}
```

And here is the Spring MVC REST controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class BookRestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findbook/{bookId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Book create(@PathVariable("bookId") String bookId, @RequestBody Book book) {
        System.out.println("The Server Heard The Request!");
        Book newBook = new Book();
        if (book.getIsbn().equals("123a")){
            newBook.setAuthor("J.K. Rowling");
            newBook.setTitle("Harry Potter");
            newBook.setIsbn(bookId);
        }
        else if(book.getIsbn().equals("b321")) {
            newBook.setAuthor("Stan Lee");
            newBook.setTitle("Spiderman");
            newBook.setIsbn(bookId);
        }
        else {
            newBook.setAuthor("Author not specified.");
            newBook.setTitle("Title note specified.");
            newBook.setIsbn(bookId);
        }
        return newBook;
    }

}
```

Comment: Know nothing about Spring but the code looks like it is expecting url `'/api/findbook/{bookId}'`, am I right?

Comment: @Icycool Thank you, but changing the line to `$http.post('/api/findbook/' + bookId, $scope.book);` did not resolve the problem.  Neither did changing the line to `$http.post('api/findbook/' + bookId, $scope.book);`.  This is my first time with either angular or REST, so I am learning by reading and experimenting all day.

Comment: Hmm you have a typo in your controller name (it is case sensitive), does it not raising an error in console log?

Comment: And `ng-app` is missing as well.

Comment: @Icycool Thank you.  But I made both changes and refreshed the `index.html` in the browser before trying again, but it still does not connect.  I made the changes also in the OP so that it is easier to read in one place.  The OP now reflects the current code in my IDE.  There is nothing in the eclipse console printout when I do this because it is all javascript.  Not sure where else to look for logs.

Comment: Is your server returning the data? how are you testing the server's response? why are you using POST to retrieve data? can't you use GET?

Comment: @wdoering Thank you for great ideas.  However, I tried each of them and still nothing happens when I click on the submit button using `123a` as the `ISBN`.  My OP now contains the calls to GET from the two controllers, in addition to a SYSO in the Spring controller to check to see if the server is called.  There is no console output, even when the SYSO is in the server controller method.

Comment: Um, how do you include your JavaScript files? Btw: the point of `@RestController` is not having to write `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: @zeroflagL When I add `<script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>` to either the start or the end of the `<body>` section, the form still does not produce any data when I click on the script.  Is there anything else I can test?

Comment: You need to include `bookController.js` as well.

Comment: Do you get any error message in console log? It is available in the developer's tool as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change $scope.findBook as follows,

```
  $scope.findBook = function() {
        $http.get('/findbook/' + bookId).then(function(response) {          
            $scope.book = response.data;
        });
    };
```

Once the promise has been resolved, it will update $scope.book and that should reflect in your HTML.

I am not sure in your code `$http.get('/findbook/' + bookId, $scope.book);`, what does $scope.book do?

Comment: I made your changes, but they do not resolve the problem.  Still nothing happens when I submit the form.  I thought $scope.book sends a book object back to the server.  I am brand new to angularis this week.  I am trying to develop an extremely simple building block so that it will be easier to learn more advanced things step by step.  Any other ideas?

Comment: You need not send anything back to the server in a GET request. Your URL may be `/findbook/1`, and that should return a Book object in JSON format. Can you check your network tab and confirm whether your AJAX request is indeed returning a JSON object

Comment: How do check the network tab?  I am testing both in eclipse and also separately in firefox.  Also, while your point about GET is valid, I need to make this work with POST given what I will do with the simple example afterwards.  I do not think that GET and POST will be any more difficult than each other because the problem is with the connection to the server.

Comment: **Tools menu --> Web Developer --> Network**. It's important you confirm whether your AJAX call is returning a JSON response before blaming the front-end.

Comment: Maybe I got it, we need to use `$scope.book = response.data;` instead of `$scope.book = response;`. I have modified the code above. Can you please try and check?

Comment: Nothing happens in the **Network** tab when I click on the button after making your changes.  I also tested both GET and POST.  And also with and without the `/api` leading the url.

Comment: Are you not able to see any request in your Network tab. It may be an error but you should.

Comment: I do not want to ask too much, but the code in the OP is so blindingly simple that it would only take a moment to recreate it on your devbox.  The Spring config might be an issue, but I created the example by downloading the angularjs branch of the spring petclinic and then deleting almost every file and folder in `/src/main/webapp` before building up the simple example.  So the spring config in my example should all be OK.  https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic

Comment: The **Network** tab shows NOTHING when I submit the form.  However, when I refresh the page, the **Network** tab shows the GET request from the page request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93213/discussion-between-codemed-and-kenneth-john).

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?  I am reading through the github code for the sample app to try to find the syntax they use to call the rest controllers, but I am not finding it yet.  Seems they use model object methods, but I cannot find the model code yet in their app.

Comment: This link might lead to the answer: https://github.com/singularity-sg/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/webapp/components/_partials/SearchController.js

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but if i remember, Spring MVC doesn't support Request Body on a GET request.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.  Also, please note that the comments indicate that this was tried with POST before trying GET.  The etiquette is to make comments interactively until an answer is arrived at.

Comment: Then build resp by asking good, well-researched questions.  meta.stackoverflow.com has lots of information about what constitutes a good question.